# Any possible way to solve Error finding/loading class

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I hope that this is just a simple issue that I have messed up on, I have been getting this Error in Intellij for the past 2 hours:

Error: Could not find or load main class algs13.MyLinked2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: algs13.MyLinked2

I have tried making copies, making new run configurations, some other stuff I don't recall and even downloading eclipse which is the IDE my professor uses but there I instead get the error:

Editor does not contain main

This is probably a useless endeavor but I'm writing this hoping I just overlooked something.

Here is the code, all i have edited is the public void delete which is commented out as I tried to see if that was the error

Sorry for this probably pointless question and thanks in advance for any effort expended in this

```
package algs13;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import stdlib.*;

/* 
 * Complete the methods below.
 * All of these methods modify the list.
 * Use the function checkInvariants to ensure that your list is well-formed after you modify it.
 * Note that this list keeps track of the number of elements N.
 * It is important that N accurately reflect the length of the list. 
 * 
 * You may not add any fields to the node or list classes.
 * You may not add any methods to the node class.
 * You may not create any new objects objects.
 * For example, you may not create a new Node, new Stack, or new ArrayList.
 * 
 *    new Node (...)  // Forbidden: create a new Node object.
 *    
 * You *may* declare variables of type Node.
 *    
 *    Node x = first; // Allowed: declare variable of type Node.
 *  
 * You may not change the item value of any existing node, only change the next pointer.
 * 
 *    x.item = ... // Forbidden
 *    x.next = ... // Allowed
 *    first  = ... // Allowed
 *
 * Each function must be independent.  
 * For example, you cannot call delete to implement remove.
 * You MAY add private methods to the list class (helper functions for the recursion). 
 * You do NOT need to use recursion for this homework.
 * You can use loops in each problem.
 */
public class MyLinked2 {
    static class Node {
        public Node (double item, Node next) { this.item = item; this.next = next; }
        public double item;
        public Node next;
    }
    int N;
    Node first;

    // delete the kth element (where k is between 0 and N-1 inclusive)
    public void delete (int k) {
//      if (k < 0 || k >= N) throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
//      if(k==0){
//          first=first.next;
//      }else{
//          Node n=first;
//          for (int i = 0; i < k-1; i++) {
//              n=n.next;
//          }
//          n=n.next.next;
//      }
//      // TODO
//      checkInvariants();
    }

    // reverse the list "in place"... 
    public void reverse () {
        // TODO 
    }

    // remove all occurrences of item from the list 
    public void remove (double item) {
        // TODO
    }

    `public static void main (String args[]) {
        //mainDebug ();
        mainRunTests ();
    }
    private static void mainDebug () {
        // Use this for debugging!
        // Add the names of helper functions if you use them.
        Trace.drawStepsOfMethod ("delete");
        Trace.drawStepsOfMethod ("reverse");
        Trace.drawStepsOfMethod ("remove");
        Trace.showObjectIdsRedundantly(true);
        Trace.run (); 
        // TODO:  Put the test here you want to debug:`

        testReverse ("11 21 31 41", "[ 41 31 21 11 ]");
        StdOut.println ("Finished tests");
    }
    private static void mainRunTests () {
        Trace.run (); // uncomment this to get drawings in showError
        testDelete (1, "11 21 31 41", "[ 11 31 41 ]");
        testDelete (2, "11 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 41 ]");
        testDelete (3, "11 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 ]");
        testDelete (1, "11 21 31 41 51", "[ 11 31 41 51 ]");
        testDelete (2, "11 21 31 41 51", "[ 11 21 41 51 ]");
        testDelete (3, "11 21 31 41 51", "[ 11 21 31 51 ]");
        testDelete (4, "11 21 31 41 51", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testDelete (0, "11 21 31 41 51", "[ 21 31 41 51 ]");
        testDelete (0, "11", "[ ]");
        testDelete (0, "11 21 31 41", "[ 21 31 41 ]");
        testDelete (0, "", "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException");
        testDelete(-1, "11 21 31", "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException");
        testDelete (3, "11 21 31", "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException");

        testReverse ("11 21 31 41", "[ 41 31 21 11 ]");
        testReverse ("11 21 31 41 51", "[ 51 41 31 21 11 ]");
        testReverse ("11 21", "[ 21 11 ]");
        testReverse ("11 21 31", "[ 31 21 11 ]");
        testReverse ("11", "[ 11 ]");
        testReverse ("", "[ ]");

        testRemove (5, "8 11 5 5 21 31 5 5 5 41", "[ 8 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 5 21 5 31 5 5 41 8", "[ 11 21 31 41 8 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 5 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 5 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 5 21 31 5 5 5 41 5 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 5 21 5 31 5 5 5 41 5 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 41 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 21 5 31 5 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 5 5 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 5 5 5 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 5 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 5 5 5 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 5 5 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 5 5 5 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 41 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 41 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31 41 5 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5 11 5 5 21 5 31 5 5 5 41 5 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5 5 11 5 5 5 21 31 5 5 41 5 5", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 11 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5 11 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5 5 11 21 31 41", "[ 11 21 31 41 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11", "[ 11 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21", "[ 11 21 ]");
        testRemove (5, "11 21 31", "[ 11 21 31 ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5 5", "[ ]");
        testRemove (5, "5 5", "[ ]");
        testRemove (5, "5", "[ ]");
        testRemove (5, "", "[ ]");
        testRemove (5.1, "5.1 5.1 5.1 5 11 5.1 5.1 21 5.1 31 5.1 5.1 41 5.1 5.1 5.1", "[ 5 11 21 31 41 ]");
        StdOut.println ("Finished tests");
    }

    /* ToString method to print */
    public String toString () { 
        // Use DecimalFormat #.### rather than String.format 0.3f to leave off trailing zeroes
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat ("#.###");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ("[ ");
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            result.append (format.format (x.item));
            result.append (" ");
        }
        result.append ("]");
        return result.toString ();
    }

    /* Method to create lists */
    public static MyLinked2 from(String s) {
        MyLinked2 result = new MyLinked2 ();
        if ("".equals (s)) return result;

        int N = 0;
        Node first = null;
        String[] nums = s.split (" ");
        for (int i = nums.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            try { 
                double num = Double.parseDouble (nums[i]); 
                first = new Node (num, first);  
                N++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException (String.format ("Bad argument \"%s\": could not parse \"%s\" as a double", s, nums[i]));
            }
        }
        result.first = first;
        result.N = N;
        return result;
    }

    static void showError (String message) {
        Trace.draw ();
        StdOut.println (message);
        //throw new Error (); // stops execution
    }
    private static void checkInvariants (String message, MyLinked2 list) {
        int num = 0;
        Node firstInCycle = null;
        {
            java.util.HashSet<Node> visited = new java.util.HashSet<>();                
            for (Node x = list.first; x!=null; x=x.next) {
                if (visited.contains(x)) {
                    firstInCycle = x;
                    break;
                }
                visited.add(x);
                num++;          
            }
        }
        if (firstInCycle != null) {
            showError (String.format ("For %s: Node list has cycle.\n"
                + "Cycle starts at Node with item=%f.\n"
                + "Refusing to run any more tests until the cycle is removed.\n"
                + "Uncomment Trace.run() in main to see a picture.\n", message, firstInCycle.item));
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (num != list.N) {
            showError (String.format ("%s: N=%d, but there are %d Nodes.", message, list.N, num));
        }
    }
    private static void check (String message, MyLinked2 actual, String expected) {
        checkInvariants (message, actual);
        if (!expected.equals (actual.toString ())) {
            showError (String.format ("%s: expected=%s, actual=%s", message, expected, actual.toString ()));
        }
    }
    private static void testDelete (int k, String list, String expected) {
        MyLinked2 actual = MyLinked2.from (list);
        String message = String.format ("[ %s ].delete( %d )", list, k);
        try {
            actual.delete (k);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            String exception = e.getClass ().getName ();
            if (! exception.equals (expected)) {
                e.printStackTrace (); // for debugging
                showError (String.format ("%s: expected=%s, actual=%s", message, expected, exception));
            }
            return;
        }
        check (message, actual, expected);
    }
    private static void testReverse (String list, String expected) {
        MyLinked2 actual = MyLinked2.from (list);
        actual.reverse ();
        String message = String.format ("[ %s ].reverse( )", list);
        check (message, actual, expected);
    }
    private static void testRemove (double item, String list, String expected) {
        MyLinked2 actual = MyLinked2.from (list);
        actual.remove (item);
        String message = String.format ("[ %s ].remove( %.2f )", list, item);
        check (message, actual, expected);
    }
}type here
```

Comment: This may be a copy/paste error, but there's a backtick ` in front of your `main` method declaration

Comment: @Jorn yeah thats a copy paste error I was using single backtick to format code but fixed it after it sugested to use 4 and it ended up staying

Comment: I would start by forgetting all your *real* code - get a simple "Hello world" app to work (including using a package). At the moment we don't know how you've compiled the code or how you're trying to run it. I very much doubt that the code in the class is the actual problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet all my other projects work fine, this particular java class is inside a folder algs13 inside algs4, all other folders under algs4 work fine. All other seperate projects work too,

Comment: Well, it sounds like it's a classpath issue somewhere, but it's likely to be hard to say more than that without looking at the details of how the project is configured etc. (I assume it has compiled without error?)

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out "Trace.run ();" solves it idk why tbh but project finally runs.